# Getting unique solutions with python cplex solution pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I have an MILP model that I try to solve with cplex python API. I need to get more than one solution. The problem is that when I get for example 50 solutions from my cplex pool, these solutions are very much similar. How can I somehow shuffle before getting these solutions and get solutions that are different than each other as much as possible without adding new constraints?

Answer (score 1):

You can use solution pool filters for that. Using a diversity filter you can make sure that solutions are sufficiently different. These filters however only work for binary variables.

You can find more details in the [solution pool documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/soln_pool/01_soln_pool_title_synopsis.html) and in the [solution pool reference documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.SolnPoolFilterInterface-class.html). Details about the filter functions can be found in the C library reference documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/addsolnpooldivfilter.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/addsolnpoolrngfilter.html).

The user manual also has an example about finding diverse solutions that uses another strategy. See [CPLEX > User's Manual for CPLEX > Discrete optimization Solution pool: generating and keeping multiple solutions > Parameters of the solution pool > Example: diverse solutions through replacement parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/soln_pool/35_eg_diversity.html)

Comment: thank you Daniel. For using add_diversity_filter(self, lb, ub, expression, weights=None, name='') I don't know what to put for the arguments. For example, what is lower band refering to? or what needs to be put as the expression? I saw the example in IBM's site but it was not clear enough.

Comment: The reference documentation of the corresponding function in the C API should give you the required details, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/addsolnpooldivfilter.html.
The documentation also has an explicit example for finding diverse solutions (using a simpler strategy): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/soln_pool/35_eg_diversity.html